# Changing the legend size in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I would like to specifically change only the legend size outputting for a Pie Chart. I've tried all methods I can find for AChartEngine, but none of them only change the legend text size. Do I have to override the onDraw function? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For setting the legend height use:

```
renderer.setLegendHeight(height);
```

You can also have the legend take only the exact space it needs:

```
renderer.setFitLegend(true);
```

To change the legend text size:

```
renderer.setLegendTextSize(textSize);
```

Comment: That works, but how do you change the actual size of the text in the legend? (It's too small)

Comment: So it seems to work, but it also changes the label size... Not sure if thats a bug or not

Comment: facing this problem; The method setLegendTextSize(int) is undefined for the type SimpleSeriesRenderer

Answer (score 1):

To change the value of chart
renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(textSize);