# I am working on the project using AFreeChart, I am unable to increase font of X-axis and Y-axis

Tags: android, linechart

**ia m using afreechart library to show the different types of graph in my application** but i am unable to increase the size of the labet on X and Y axis on line chart it is not relecting the changes ...and i am unable to make the size the that label text to increase
my code is here

```html
    package com.chartingapp.chartview;

import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.afree.chart.AFreeChart;
import org.afree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.afree.chart.LegendItemCollection;
import org.afree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.afree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions;
import org.afree.chart.labels.CategoryItemLabelGenerator;
import org.afree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.afree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.afree.chart.renderer.category.LineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.afree.chart.title.TextTitle;
import org.afree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.afree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.afree.graphics.SolidColor;
import org.afree.ui.RectangleInsets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.chartingapp.ChartView;
import com.chartingapp.R.color;
import com.chartingapp.util.CommonUtil;

public class LineChartView1 extends ChartView {
 private GraphicalView mGraphView;

 private static TextTitle title;
 private static LegendItemCollection items;
 public CommonUtil m_Inst = CommonUtil.getInstance();
 private static float textSize = 30;

 public LineChartView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  final AFreeChart chart = createChart1(createDataset1());
  setChart(chart);
 }

 /***************************** start *********************************/
 private static AFreeChart createChart1(CategoryDataset dataset) {
  AFreeChart chart1 = ChartFactory.createLineChart(CommonUtil.repName,
    "", "Value", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,
    false);

  chart1.setBackgroundPaintType(new SolidColor(Color.WHITE));

  final CategoryPlot plot = chart1.getCategoryPlot();

  plot.setBackgroundPaintType(new SolidColor(Color.WHITE));
  plot.setDomainGridlinePaintType(new SolidColor(Color.BLACK));
  plot.setRangeGridlinePaintType(new SolidColor(Color.BLACK));
  plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
  plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
  plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

  LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
  renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(dataset.getRowCount(), true);
  renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

  for (int i = 0; i < dataset.getRowCount(); i++) {
   renderer.setSeriesStroke(i, 2.0f);
   renderer.getSeriesItemLabelPaintType(color.GreenYellow);

   /**********************************************/
   renderer.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(i,
     new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

      @Override
      public String generateRowLabel(CategoryDataset dataset,
        int row) {
       return String.valueOf(dataset.getRowKey(row));
      }

      @Override
      public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset,
        int row, int column) {
       return String.valueOf(dataset.getValue(row, column));
      }

      @Override
      public String generateColumnLabel(
        CategoryDataset dataset, int column) {
       return String.valueOf(dataset.getColumnKey(column));
      }
     });
   /**********************************************/
  }

  plot.setRenderer(renderer);
  plot.setFixedLegendItems(items);
  plot.setWeight(40);
  CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
  domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions
    .createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0));

  return chart1;

 }

 private CategoryDataset createDataset1() {

  /******************************************************************/
  /****** Argument for Adding Value in dataset *****/
  /* 1st Argument:- Value */
  /* 2nd Argument:- Label for series */
  /* 3rd Argument:- Label for domain axis */
  /***********************************************/
  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
  /********* If no of row is greater than number of column ***********/

  if (CommonUtil.lineChartType == 0) {
   if (CommonUtil.dataList.get(0).size() > CommonUtil.dataList.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CommonUtil.dataList.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < CommonUtil.dataList.get(i).size(); j++) {
      dataset.addValue(Double.valueOf(CommonUtil.dataList
        .get(i).get(j)), String
        .valueOf(CommonUtil.verticalLabel.get(i)),
        String.valueOf(CommonUtil.horizontalLabel
          .get(j)));
      System.out.println("Series:- " + i + "  "
        + CommonUtil.dataList.get(i).get(j) + "("
        + CommonUtil.horizontalLabel.get(j) + ")");
     }
    }
   } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < CommonUtil.dataList.get(0).size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < CommonUtil.dataList.size(); j++) {
      dataset.addValue(Double.valueOf(CommonUtil.dataList
        .get(j).get(i)), String
        .valueOf(CommonUtil.horizontalLabel.get(i)),
        String.valueOf(CommonUtil.verticalLabel.get(j)));
      System.out.println("Series:- " + i + "  "
        + CommonUtil.dataList.get(j).get(i) + "("
        + CommonUtil.verticalLabel.get(j) + ")");
     }
    }
   }
  } else {
   for (int i = 0; i < CommonUtil.dataList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < CommonUtil.dataList.get(i).size(); j++) {
     dataset.addValue(
       Double.valueOf(CommonUtil.dataList.get(i).get(j)),
       String.valueOf(CommonUtil.horizontalLabel.get(i)),
       String.valueOf(CommonUtil.verticalLabel.get(j)));
    }
   }
  }
  /******************************************************************/
  return dataset;
 }

 /********************************* end *****************************/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using achartengine(from your imports) i guess, thus you can change the text size :

```
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(size);
renderer.setLegendHeight(height);
```

It's a more flexible library, have a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818945/changing-the-legend-size-in-achartengine).

Comment: Mr. issathink, both options are not available to use with renderer, I tried it already so can you please suggest me other way to solve it ?